# Why is Proof of Work necessary in Blockchain?

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, digital-signature, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

My question is quite simple, why can't every node in the network follow the same principle for verifying transactions:

1. Check that the transaction has a unique ID
2. Check that the digital signature is correct using the public-key of the person sending money

- No one can fake sending money on the behalf of someone else because
  they do not have that person's private-key and hence cannot create a
  valid digital signature for that transaction. No one can copy a
  previous transaction with a valid digital signature and broadcast to
  other nodes again because the ID must be unique.
- This would also remove the notion of "blocks" in a "chain" and lead
  to a simple ledger.

I am aware that blockchains already implement this simple system of digital signatures. What I don't understand is, what is the necessity of further verification through proof-of-work? How could someone possibly create an illegitimate block (with one or more illegitimate transactions) which would require this further layer of security? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing double spending problem. If you have some amount of currency you can create unlimited amount of valid transactions. How you would know which one is correct?

This is why Proof-of-Work was implemented. It allows nodes to check which transactions are valid, and which try to double spend.

Comment: Why not just throw out all the transactions of the user in the current block if they send you an invalid transaction (one they cannot afford)? Surely, no one else could have constructed that invalid transaction as the ID must be unique and the digital signature must be correct. I still don't understand the necessity of Proof of Work. Would appreciate further clarification.

Comment: @BillBaits What do you mean by invalid transaction? In my examples transaction are always valid, they are generated by the same person, who has private key. Every new transaction has different ID, since `ID=hash(tx)`. Imagine you are node in the network. You received 2 blocks, transaction1 in block1 sends you some currency from Bob's account, transaction2 in block2 sends the same amount of currency to Alice's account from Bob's account. Bob tries to buy something from you. How would you determine which block (and underlying transaction) is correct?

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean now. Bob sends transaction1 to one miner and transaction2 to another miner. They both construct different blocks and now there is a discrepancy. I must not have grasped the type of problems that arise from having a fully decentralized network.